# singleton instance working after sometime not working in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi in the below trying congigure the wifi via BLE device .But below code working for sometime and retesting the code not working for next time.

Can any one help me where I did the wrong .I am thinking while using singleton class problem occurring.

Can any one help on the below issue what I am facing

PesNative.java:

```
case PesConstants.STATUS.RESET_PROVISION:
              //  if(pesManager != null) {
                String reset_ble_name = uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.BLE_NAME); // BLE_NAME | for testing
                String device_Prefix =uri.getQueryParameter(PesConstants.PES_DEVICE_PREFIX);
                Log.d("jyothi", reset_ble_name);
                pesManager.initPesDevice(context, reset_ble_name);
                checkdeviceStatus(context,device_Prefix,reset_ble_name);
                pesManager.changeProvisioningMode(PesConstants.PROVISIONING_ACTION.RESET_PROVISION);
                checkAPIExecutedTime(loggingData);

                break;
```

PesManager.java:

```
public void initPesDevice(Activity activity, String deviceIdentifier) {
        //Disconnect the device in provisioning mode if already connected
        context = activity;
        disConnectDevice();

        //Disconnect the device in data mode if already connected
        PesBleDevice.getInstance(webView, activity, deviceIdentifier); // this will update the instance variable for disconnection.
        pesDevice = PesBleDevice.getInstance(webView, activity, "PES_" + deviceIdentifier);
        this.deviceIdentifier=deviceIdentifier;
        PesBleDevice.deleteInstance();
      //  pesDevice =  PesBleDevice.getInstance(webView,activity,"PES_" + deviceIdentifier); // This is needed after wifi provision for resetting wifi provision

    }
```

Pesbledevice.java:

```
 public boolean changeProvisioningMode(int action) {
        byte[] value = new byte[1];
        switch (action) {
            case 1://reset provisioning, required for reconfigure wi-fi
                value[0] = (byte) 0x00;
                break;
            case 2://reboot
                value[0] = (byte) 0xFF;
                break;
            case 3://reset identity
                value[0] = (byte) 0xA5;
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Invalid action");
                return false;
        }

        ENHOBleCallback writeProvisioningModeCallback = new ENHOBleCallback() {
            @Override
            void onSuccess(Object obj) {
                try {
                    //super.onSuccess(obj);
                    Log.d("PesBleDevice", "Inside writeProvisioningMode callback");
                    Log.d("PesBleDevice","Reading Success object = " + obj.toString());
                    disconnect();
                    PesBleDevice.deleteInstance();
                    if (scanDelayRequired) {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                        scanDelayRequired = false;
                    }
                    activity.runOnUiThread(
                            () -> PesHelper.jsFunction(webView, "1", PesHelper.JS_DID_SET_PROVISIONING_MODE));
                } catch (InterruptedException ebce) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Caught exception : ", ebce);
                }
            }

            @Override
            void onFailure(Object obj) {
                try {
                    if (mRetries >= 3) {
                        //super.onFailure(obj);
                        Log.d("PesBleDevice","Reading Failure object = " + obj.toString());
                        Log.d(TAG, "changeProvisioningMode, Failed to write provisioning mode");
                        disconnect();
                        PesBleDevice.deleteInstance();
                        if (scanDelayRequired) {
                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                            scanDelayRequired = false;
                        }
                        activity.runOnUiThread(
                                () -> PesHelper.jsFunction(webView, "0", "reset provision failed", PesHelper.JS_DID_SET_PROVISIONING_MODE));
                        mRetries = 0;
                    } else {
                        disconnect();
                        mRetries++;
                        clearCallbacks();
                        changeProvisioningMode(action);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ebce) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Caught exception", ebce);
                }
            }
        };
        if (getConnectionState() != BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            ENHOBleCallback scanStateCb = new ENHOBleCallback() {
                @Override
                void onSuccess(Object obj) {
                    try {
                        super.onSuccess(obj);
                        Log.d(TAG, "changeProvisioningMode, Device found in scan");
                        Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside changeProvisioningMode| changeProvisioningMode, Device found in scan");

                        /*if(bleDevice != null) {
                            unpairDevice(bleDevice);
                        }*/
                        ENHOBleCallback connectionStateCb = new ENHOBleCallback() {
                            @Override
                            void onSuccess(Object obj) {
                                try {
                                    //super.onSuccess(obj);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "changeProvisioningMode, connected to GATT server");
                                    Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside changeProvisioningMode| changeProvisioningMode, connected to GATT server");

                                    ENHOBleCallback serviceDiscoveryCb = new ENHOBleCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        void onSuccess(Object obj) {
                                            try {
                                                super.onSuccess(obj);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "changeProvisioningMode, discovered services");
                                                Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside changeProvisioningMode| changeProvisioningMode, discovered services");

                                                List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
                                                displayGattServices(gattServices);

                                                if (writeCharacteristicBytes(PES_DEVICE_SERVICE_COMMAND_UUID, PES_DEVICE_CHARS_RESET_PROVISION_UUID, value)) {
                                                    characteristicWriteListenerQueue.add(writeProvisioningModeCallback);
                                                    scanDelayRequired = true;
                                                } else {
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "changeProvisioningMode, write error in provisioning mode");
                                                    Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside changeProvisioningMode| changeProvisioningMode, write error in provisioning mode");

                                                    writeProvisioningModeCallback.onFailure(0);
                                                }
                                            } catch (ENHOBleCallbackException ebce) {
                                                Log.e(TAG, "Connection check already handled", ebce);
                                                Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside changeProvisioningMode->ENHOBleCallbackException | Connection check already handled" + ebce);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        void onFailure(Object obj) {
                                            try {
                                                super.onFailure(obj);
                                                Log.d(TAG, "changeProvisioningMode, Service discovery failed");
                                                Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside changeProvisioningMode->changeProvisioningMode, Service discovery failed");
                                                writeProvisioningModeCallback.onFailure(0);
                                            } catch (ENHOBleCallbackException ebce) {
                                                Log.e(TAG, "Connection check already handled", ebce);
                                                Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside changeProvisioningMode->ENHOBleCallbackException | Connection check already handled" + ebce);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    };

                                    Thread.sleep(200);
                                    discoverServciesForced(serviceDiscoveryCb);

                                    //servicesDiscoveredChangeListenerQueue.add(serviceDiscoveryCb);
                                    //bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                                } catch (InterruptedException ebce) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Connection check already handled", ebce);
                                    Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice-Inside changeProvisioningMode->InterruptedException | Connection check already handled" + ebce);

                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            void onFailure(Object obj) {
                                try {
                                    //super.onFailure(obj);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "changeProvisioningMode, failed to connect to device");
                                    Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice- Inside changeProvisioningMode method | failed to connect to device");
                                    writeProvisioningModeCallback.onFailure(0);
                                } catch (ENHOBleCallbackException ebce) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Connection check already handled", ebce);
                                    Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice| Connection check already handled" + ebce);
                                }

                            }
                        };
                        if (connectToGATTServer()) {
                            connectionStateChangeListenerQueue.add(connectionStateCb);
                        } else {
                            writeProvisioningModeCallback.onFailure(0);
                        }
                    } catch (ENHOBleCallbackException ebce) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Connection check already handled", ebce);
                        Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice| Connection check already handled" + ebce);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                void onFailure(Object obj) {
                    try {
                        super.onFailure(obj);
                        mRetries = 3;
                        writeProvisioningModeCallback.onFailure("");
                        Log.d(TAG, "failed to find device during provisioning mode");
                        Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice- Inside changeProvisioningMode method | failed to find device");
                    } catch (ENHOBleCallbackException ebce) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Connection check already handled", ebce);
                    }
                }
            };

            deviceScanListenerQueue.add(scanStateCb);
            startScan();
            return true;
        } else {
            if (writeCharacteristicBytes(PES_DEVICE_SERVICE_COMMAND_UUID, PES_DEVICE_CHARS_RESET_PROVISION_UUID, value)) {
                characteristicWriteListenerQueue.add(writeProvisioningModeCallback);
                return true;
            } else {
                try {
                    writeProvisioningModeCallback.onFailure("");
                } catch (ENHOBleCallbackException ebce) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Connection check already handled", ebce);
                    Timber.tag("PES").i("PesBleDevice| Connection check already handled" + ebce);

                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```